# Inheritance of models with relationships (hasOne and hasMany)

Tags: extjs

How to inherit from a model that has `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationships? It is necessary to preserve these relationships.

I made an example in the sandbox: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22fi

The model `Fiddle.model.User2` is inherited from`Fiddle.model.User`.

In the file `app.js` User2 I connect to the repository. If you connect `User`, then everything will work. But when using the `User2` model, the links do not work: the`getAddress()`method returns empty, and the`getUser()`method does not work.

Comment: The ExtJS associations have so many issues (at least in v4.2) that it is much easier to just write your own associations. Althought if you wanted to use the original associations, I would recommend putting a breakpoint in the [`Ext.data.Model`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Model.js-1.html) in the `Model.onExtended()` part.

Comment: @MarthyM I heard that associations got better in ExtJS 5 and 6; so much better that they had to find new features for v6 their engineers could utterly fail on, most notably, the ChainedStore.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Associations work perfectly. But there are problems with inheritance. I'll try to contact Sencha Inc. technical support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sencha Technical Support Answer**

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported.
But we do have an open feature request to add this functionality.

Please not as it is a feature request and not a bug, there is no guarantee of when or if it will be added to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

From [the code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Model.js-1.html#line3436), they either forgot it or it is not supported. For a definitive answer, you will have to make a ticket with Sencha support. The functions for everything that is mixed together from the current class and the parent class have a `proto` parameter that contains the parent class:

```
    Model.initIdentifier(data, cls, proto);
    Model.initFields(data, cls, proto);
    Model.initValidators(data, cls, proto);
```

while associations don't have a proto parameter, so they are only taken from the current class:

```
        Model.initAssociations(schema, data, cls);
```

However, it may be completely possible that this is intended behaviour. The documentation of e.g. [`fields`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-fields) states explicitly:

> Extending a Model class will inherit all the `fields` from the superclass / ancestor classes.

while the documentation of e.g. [`hasOne`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-hasOne) states (emphasis by me):

> One or more `Ext.data.schema.HasOne` associations for **this** model.

Please ask Sencha Support for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!